# While installing openstack on Ubuntu 18.04, I am stuck at error: cannot uninstall 'simplejson'

Tags: git, ubuntu-18.04, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install **openstack (single node)** on machine with **Ubuntu 18.04**, I did following steps:
update and upgrade ubuntu, installed git, cloned devstack
then after running stack.sh, I am **stuck at "Error: Cannot uninstall 'simplejson'**. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall. "
I **tried "Force=yes ./stack.sh"** but no help, also "**sudo apt-get remove simplejson"** but it cannot find package, also **"pip uninstall simplejson"** but does same error "It is a distutils installed project and thus we ..."

Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the pip install command. Make the following change to the devstack code:

1. Navigate to the devstack folder.
2. Edit the inc/python file
3. Change line 198:

   from: $cmd_pip $upgrade $install_test_reqs \

   to: $cmd_pip $upgrade $install_test_reqs --ignore-installed \

Answer (score 4):

meh. only way to get rid of it is:
sudo apt purge python3-simplejson

then rerun ./stack.sh

18.04.4 BB

Comment: A little description may helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above from [edureka](https://www.edureka.co/community/65075/error-cannot-uninstall-simplejson-not-able-install-ubuntu) is no longer valid.

In the newer versions, the 'devstack/inc/python' file has changed.

The line that needs to be changed is found within the `pip_install` function. At line no 192

CHANGE FROM

```
$cmd_pip $upgrade \
```

TO

```
$cmd_pip $upgrade --ignore-installed \
```